# Typescript - Narrowing union types for nested object props

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type DesignValueType = "text" | "html" | "image";
type BaseDesignValue<TType extends DesignValueType, TProps> = TProps & {
  type: TType;
};
type DesignValueText = BaseDesignValue<"text", { text: string }>;
type DesignValueHtml = BaseDesignValue<"html", { html: string }>;
type DesignValueImage = BaseDesignValue<"image", { url: string }>;
type DesignValue = DesignValueText | DesignValueHtml | DesignValueImage;
type DesignValues<TInitialValues> = Record<keyof TInitialValues, DesignValue>;

const initialValues = {
  name: { type: "text" as const, text: "" },
  handler: { type: "text" as const, text: "" },
  text: { type: "html" as const, html: "" },
  profile: { type: "image" as const, url: "" },
};

const displayName = (values: DesignValues<typeof initialValues>) => {
  // Property 'text' does not exist on type 'DesignValue'.
  // Property 'text' does not exist on type 'DesignValueHtml'.
  return values.name.text
}
```

The goal is to make TS understand the prop `name` in `values` is a `DesignValueText` by comparing its `type` prop somehow.

Here is the [playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBLA5gOwGoEMA2BXCAKuNALxQBEwEAHsOVAD4UAWwAttvU+Ym5shHIBuAFChIUAEKZ4EOEjRY8EADwEiEmlVQATeLAQoMOfBogAaKAQAKAJwD2YeAD4oZGw6dQAZFADeIlBQ4hAAXFZmogC+oiEGCsbKBFpuUjJyhoomqpRa5JZ+wVrh8MC2iKjIUFHOscTxRkr4ABLs2KnSsvKN2SrkrBz5-lAD2CVlFVU1dRLdWcoAknwCHelzifh9vPyCBVC4tmNQpeWV1bVi9etNpA3zpilM19mtHIx3GxBLOzPQz8rwNQLVCIYCIHA3FypABKEAAxvZbDoVABrCAgewAMyswNB4OwkMs-3wFxECNQpSgFTxEOy+jIASCqEwbDCwxC4VytHoMig5NKliotE59Ci5kCI0wumwEFs4UKHIoQroUF5-OAguKFFF4qCyvlwWInNGPP06ssoxF1V1UDADkxiBlBsVPGWglVZvsFI1+0OVrFIhiIjJXspOkQ8DA2EwIAAcizbgAKABudPCxIQKhCWKpILBtIBzgAlG5XIyoAB6CtQOyOWWgKAAcmVjagOnsCCgqHswCgNAjva9hokjYzjYAdBKqzXPPWQE2W22O-pu73+5Sh3FR5lPq9sBOJbYIMADqgoKmAePmazx8rAyIgA)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a mapped type: https://tsplay.dev/WoYa9N

Comment: First, which part of your code is the problem statement, and which part is your attempted solution? Second, why not simply use `values: typeof initialValues`? After all, `initialValues` already has the shape you are trying to painstakingly recreate with `DesignValues`? Why are you trying to recreate a type you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to map over the keys and [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the right type:

```
type DesignValues<TInitialValues extends Record<any, DesignValue>> = {
    [K in keyof TInitialValues]: Extract<DesignValue, { type: TInitialValues[K]["type"] }>;
};

const displayName = (values: DesignValues<typeof initialValues>) => {
  return values.name.text // okay
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBLA5gOwGoEMA2BXCAKuNALxQBEwEAHsOVAD4UAWwAttvU+Ym5shHIBuAFChIUAEKZ4EOEjRY8EADwEiEmlVQATeLAQoMOfBogAaKAQAKAJwD2YeAD4oZGw6dQAZFADeIlBQ4hAAXFZmogC+oiEGCsbKBFpuUjJyhoomqpRa5JZ+wVrh8MC2iKjIUFHOscTxRkr4ABLs2KnSsvKN2SrkrBz5-lAD2CVlFVU1dRLdWcoAknwCHelzifh9vPyCBVC4tmNQpeWV1bVi9etNpA3zpilM19mtHIx3GxBLOzPQz8rwNQLVCIYCIHA3fRaCC6fQAJQgAGN7LYdCpMKgQJZ-vhnK4yAEgkEANoAaSgFSgAGsICB7AAzKzA0Hg7CQgC64QAorRbJhEcAVDiLMMQuECMywRDsvAyeziZRiOR2edoqIRMjUKUKSCpWyZalCVBUJg2GFRcRwrlaPQZFBNaVLFRaFb6FFzIERhidNgILZwoUxRRnXQoHaHcAncUKG6PUEQwHgpaWG1bfoI5ZRq7qnGoGAHPTEL7E0GeMtBGH0-YtZH9ods+6RDERBrq9qdIh4GBsJgQAA5U23AAUADcZeFhYCQgydSzpQDnABKNyuI22CDAA6oKBjgEAOhNZr3IabQA)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar situation and help of @kelsny's answer. I managed to narrow down union types which are belongs to nested property.

I have this type definition generated by tool for API response:

```js
type Sitemap = {
  type?: 'Page';
  slug?: string | null;
  seo?: { 
    type: 'Seo'; 
    noIndex?: boolean | null 
  } | null;
  content?:
    | { type?: 'Home' }
    | {
        type: 'CategoryPage';
        categories?: Array<{
          catID: string,
          name: string,
          order: number,
          relations: string[]
        }> 
        published?: boolean | null;
        globalCanonical?: { type?: 'Page'; slug?: string | null } | null;
        localizedCanonical?: { type?: 'Page'; slug?: string | null } | null;
      }
    | {
        type: 'HomePage';
        bannerImgPath?: string;
        bannerTitle?: string;
        globalCanonical?: { type?: 'Page'; slug?: string | null } | null;
        localizedCanonical?: { type?: 'Page'; slug?: string | null } | null;
      }
    | { 
        type: 'StartPage';
        link?: string | null;
      }
    | { type: 'SystemPage', settings?:number[], }
    | { type: 'LandingPage' }
    | null;
};
```

and I want `SiteMap` type with specific `content` Type. In other words, I want to narrow `content` property's union types to specific ones, but I need entire `Sitemap` type definition.

So I iterate over on `Sitemap`'s property and when it's `content` I use `Extract` utility for narrowing.

```js
type CategoryPage = {
  [Key in keyof Sitemap]: Sitemap[Key] extends Sitemap['content']
    ? Extract<Sitemap['content'], { type: 'CategoryPage' }>
    : Sitemap[Key]
};

/*
* This results:
*  
*  {
*    type?: 'Page';
*    slug?: string | null;
*    seo?: { 
*      type: 'Seo'; 
*      noIndex?: boolean | null 
*    } | null;
*    content?: {
*      type: 'CategoryPage';
*      categories?: Array<{
*        catID: string,
*        name: string,
*        order: number,
*        relations: string[]
*      }> 
*      published?: boolean | null;
*      globalCanonical?: { type?: 'Page'; slug?: string | null } | null;
*      localizedCanonical?: { type?: 'Page'; slug?: string | null } | null;
*    }
*  }
*/
*/
```

another example:

```js
type HomePage = {
  [Key in keyof Sitemap]: Sitemap[Key] extends Sitemap['content']
    ? Extract<Sitemap['content'], { type: 'HomePage' }>
    : Sitemap[Key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by using some conditionals and replacing the `Record` with an object with indexed notation but I don't know why this is specifically working, to be honest.

```
type DesignValueText = { type: "text"; text: string };
type DesignValueHtml = { type: "html"; html: string };
type DesignValueImage = { type: "image"; url: string };
type DesignValue = DesignValueText | DesignValueHtml | DesignValueImage;
type DesignSchema = Record<string, DesignValue["type"]>;
type DesignValues<TInitialValues extends DesignSchema> = {
  [K in keyof TInitialValues]: TInitialValues[K] extends "text"
    ? DesignValueText
    : TInitialValues[K] extends "html"
    ? DesignValueHtml
    : TInitialValues[K] extends "image"
    ? DesignValueImage
    : never;
};

const schema = {
  name: "text",
  handler: "text",
  text: "html",
  profile: "image",
} satisfies DesignSchema;

const displayName = (values: DesignValues<typeof schema>) => {
  return values.name.text
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBLA5gOwGoEMA2BXCAKhAB7BQC8UA3lKJAFxQBEwJwTA3LW4-MAE6JUyKAF8OAKDrQ4SNFjwQAEsAC22CtVrgIjJgAs12TlEPreAoSPFSdsBCgw58ASVWZk0SjWl7E7zxNcfmwLQWExSWl7OSdFTVlHBXwiUigAHxik52UjDKz5HLcPCCi7RLQAZQBjfQh3TQAlCGqAe34AEwAePnDkABoCuPwAbRYdJgBdAD4yyCHkhC6CF1REYEQcRfgoNghUDp2K1Bq692nNKgkoKBGAaSghKABrCBBWgDMoFbWNrZz4JNGD91ptsNt7pNdqR9odmKxSExrjcoAB%20BY5VLAZE3YGrUH-RTwSHQ1gHHYGIxIlFojGKFTqHFQPG-MEQu5Qvbk5j%20ErUlHo46LYqeJmMVAQABuEH4khsEjaqD4UHgtXqmEuyNQmFUunhbCY-WR%20kwB2wMr0CPYRpuVr0ZmMNqgYH4n0Q5r8AQghokohVmA28A%20iAQQ1O6skCtaSrIHUQ8DA2EwIAAcjqvFAABSSgGMIUArrST4qtXnACUFAuVxu-AgwGCqCgOaJADptbqW1bfRIgA)